# Why can't generic methods choose a specific method when the generic one doesn't match?

Tags: c#, generics

Given the following class:

```
public static class MWE
{
    public static void Foo<T, TColl>(Expression<Func<IFoo, bool>> bar, TColl foos)
        where TColl : IEnumerable<T>
    {
    }

    public static void Foo<T, TColl>(Expression<Func<IFoo, T>> bar, TColl foos)
        where TColl : IEnumerable<T>
    {
    }

    static MWE()
    {
        Foo(bar => bar.GetThing(), new List<IThing>());
        Foo(bar => bar.GetBool(), new List<IThing>());
    }
}

public interface IFoo
{
    IThing GetThing();

    bool GetBool();
}
```

I get a compilation error on the second call to `Foo`, complaining that there's no conversion from `List<IThing>` to `IEnumerable<bool>`. It seems to me that the compiler doesn't see the first overload, although it matches (and the second doesn't).

Why? Is there a way these two methods can co-exist and work?

Comment: Try explicitly stating the generic parameters for `Foo`. Something like: `Foo<IThing,List<IThing>>(bar => bar.GetBool(), new List<IThing>());` It can't correctly infer what `T` is supposed to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first overload can't be called because there isn't enough information to infer the generic arguments.   You use *one* of the generic arguments, `TColl`, but you never use `T` in the signature, so there is no way to infer it.

If you explicitly specify the generic arguments, then the first overload will be chosen and will work properly.

If you simply remove the second generic argument entirely, and use `IEnumerable<T>` in the signature instead of `TColl` it will simplify those the methods and allow both of your existing calls to function properly.

Comment: Interesting. But when resolving `TCollection` to something, isn't there enough information to know what `T` is?

Comment: @TomasLycken Not given how C#'s generic type inference works.  It doesn't consider generic constraints.

Answer (score 2):

Generic type constraints (`where ...`) are not used for generic type inference (inferring `T` and `TCall` when you don't state them explicitly). You might think that type `T` in your first overload might be inferred to be `IThing` because you pass `List<IThing>` as `TColl`, but because of the above it's not so.

Since generic types cannot be inferred - this method does not participate in overload resolution and second method is used. That fails and you see compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this one first:

```
public static void Foo<T, TColl>(Expression<Func<IFoo, T>> bar, TColl foos)
    where TColl : IEnumerable<T>
```

How does the compiler figure out what `T` is? It looks at the expression you pass it (`bar`) and looks to see what the return type is. From that, it can infer `T`. `bar` returns an `IThing`, so `T` is `IThing` and `TColl` is `IEnumerable<IThing>`.

Now look at this one:

```
public static void Foo<T, TColl>(Expression<Func<IFoo, bool>> bar, TColl foos)
    where TColl : IEnumerable<T>
```

What's `T`? It's not the type returned by `bar`, that's hardcoded to be `bool`. So what is it? The compiler can't tell, so the only way you can use this function is if you *explicitly* tell it what the generic parameters are:

```
Foo<IThing,List<IThing>>(bar => bar.GetBool(), new List<IThing>());
```

^ this will compile.

Without being able to figure out what `T` is, it has to use the first function, infer `T` is `bool` and then it will complain because you are passing it an `IEnumerable<IThing>` when it expects an `IEnumerable<bool>`

Comment: I'll ask you the same follow-up as I did @Servy: Why can the compiler not infer `T` from the collection (which must implement `IEnumerable<T>`)?

Comment: Because that determines what `TColl` is, not what `T` is. The compiler won't go the extra step of inferring that since `TColl` is `IEnumerable<T>` and `TColl` is `IEnumerable<IThing>`, therefore `T` must be `IThing`. You could see how following that chain of logic could get you horribly lost pretty quickly and clearly the designers decided it wasn't worth the complexity.